# How do I add line numbers to text?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, awk, sed

My text is:

```
Hi
Bye
Nope
Sorry
Cya
Chill
```

How can I make it:

```
[1] Hi
[2] Bye
[3] Nope
```

and so on and so forth?

Comment: Try `cat filename | nl`

Comment: What you show is not just adding line numbers, you skip empty lines for numbering, and wrap the output to a single line. Please edit your post to make it more clear what you want.

Answer (score 7):

The `nl` ("number lines") utility does this:

```
$ cat file
Hi
Bye

Nope
Sorry

Cya
Chill

$ nl file
     1  Hi
     2  Bye

     3  Nope
     4  Sorry

     5  Cya
     6  Chill
```

There are a number of options to `nl` that you can play around with. It also does page numbering etc.

Some implementations of `cat` also supports line numbering:

```
$ cat -n file
     1  Hi
     2  Bye
     3
     4  Nope
     5  Sorry
     6
     7  Cya
     8  Chill
```

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '{ print NR, $0 }' file
1 Hi
2 Bye
3
4 Nope
5 Sorry
6
7 Cya
8 Chill
```

Or, if you don't want numbering of blank lines:

```
$ awk '$0 { print ++nr, $0; next } { print }' file
1 Hi
2 Bye

3 Nope
4 Sorry

5 Cya
6 Chill
```

With `awk`, it's also easy to do special formatting:

```
$ awk -vOFS="\t" '$0 { print "[" ++nr "]", $0; next } { print }' file
[1]     Hi
[2]     Bye

[3]     Nope
[4]     Sorry

[5]     Cya
[6]     Chill
```

Or...

```
$ awk -vOFS=":\t" '$0 { printf("[%03d]%s%s\n", ++nr, OFS, $0); next } { print }' file
[001]:  Hi
[002]:  Bye

[003]:  Nope
[004]:  Sorry

[005]:  Cya
[006]:  Chill
```

From the `paste` manual (on OpenBSD):

```
$ sed '=' file | paste -s -d '\t\n' - -
1       Hi
2       Bye
3
4       Nope
5       Sorry
6
7       Cya
8       Chill
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk '{printf "%s.\t%s\n",NR,$0}' file`

Additionally you can just use the `nl` command.  So like:

`cat /path/to/file | nl > /path/to/output`